# Dynamically updating after save (Lightswitch HTML)

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Basically I have an ordering System which consists of a ViewOrderScreen and AddPartScreen screen.

the ViewOrderScreen contains a table view which displays all the parts that have been added. It also displays a Total field which is referenced from the tblOrders.

Now what I want to achieve is this: when I add a part, a Dialog window opens up, I select the part, add the quantity, then hit save. The dialog box then disappears and the part is displayed in the table view. However the Total field is not updated until I refresh the page.

So my question, how can I get this value to update everytime I add a part?

I am using a data item (Money) called Display which currently displays this value... thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using the html or Silverlight client?

Comment: I am using the HTML Client with JavaScript and C#, which retrieves the data from SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works a treat, but my main problem was the Total field not being updated on the JavaScript code. i did all the calculation in C# but this was updating the data at thw wrong time

```
setInterval(function() {

    var a = parseFloat(contentItem.screen.OrderRequest.Total);
    var b = parseFloat(contentItem.screen.OrderRequest.CarriageCost);


    contentItem.dataBind("value", function(newValue) {
        var c = a + b;


        element.innerText = "£" + c;
    });
},500);
```

Comment: You need to add an event handler on the collection you're adding to so that when your collection changes you can iterate over it and work your total. I'm not in the office right now but I'll find a reference to what I mean or actual code later.

Comment: I had a few moments longer to kill here and found the resource I think will help... [Michael Washington's Lightswitch Site](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/168/Writing-JavaScript-That-Implements-The-Binding-Pattern-In-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx). Its the addChangeListener method under "Two methods to bind them together" I think will be of most help. Hope that helps.

Comment: ill have a go at this over the next few days :) thanks